# Resources on Italian Game, Two Knights Defense with 4. d3 h6 and quick ...g5

Tags: opening, italian-game, two-knights

Do any books or other resources discuss this variation for Black? Does it have a name?

The general idea is to go 4...h6, then ...d6 and ...g5 in some order, depending on what White does.

S. Mamedyarov plays this line a lot.

Sample line:

```
 [FEN ""]
    1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. d3 h6 5. c3 d6 6. O-O g5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FM Andrey Terekhov's [Two Knights Defense repertoire on Chessable](https://www.chessable.com/book.php?bid=18646) uses this variation against 4.d3.

That repertoire deserves to be more widely known: it's one of the best on Chessable, the author updates it frequently, and it's free!

In the introductory text of 4.d3 h6 he notes:

> In the beginning, this line has been mostly used as a surprise weapon, but in the past two years it developed its own body of theory. GM Alexey Kuzmin published a couple of articles summarizing the latest developments in this line in "ChessBase Magazine" (in 2018) and in Russian "64" (2019) .

So those are sources too.

And according to [a ChessPub discussion](https://www.chesspub.com/cgi-bin/chess/YaBB.pl?num=1568098530/12), there are also two analyzed games in this line in Alexander Ipatov: *Unconventional Approaches to Modern Chess Volume 1*; Thinkers Publishing 2019, although I don't see it in that book's list of contents.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! If I understand correctly the games analysed in Ipatov's book discuss a setup with ...h6 and ...g6, not ...g5, which seems like a different idea.

Comment: That comment mentions 6...g5, and the games MVL - Mamedyarov 2018 and Fossan - Hammer 2018. But I don't have the book, can't check. I think ...g6 is the older idea and ...g5 is the new one that is being played only since a few years.